# how can I add items from an array as a class

Tags: php, css, arrays, facebook, class

I am new at php, so please be kind.

I am building a script that gets the number of facebook likes from facebook pages.

Then it sorts them, I have found a way to add the page's profile picture using css, however the only class I am able to add is a url. how can I give each thumbnail it's own class, which I can then apply the css to?

here is my code:

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
$new_array = array();
$sortable_array = array();

if (count($array) > 0) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                if ($k2 == $on) {
                    $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    switch ($order) {
        case SORT_ASC:
            asort($sortable_array);
        break;
        case SORT_DESC:
            arsort($sortable_array);
        break;
    }

    foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
        $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
    }
  }

  return $new_array;
  }


  function getLikes($arr){
$urls = "";

// Add urls to check for likes
for($i = 0;$i < count($arr);$i++) {
    if($urls != "") $urls .= ",https://www.facebook.com/";
    $urls .= $arr[$i];
}

// Retreive info from Facebook 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=https://www.facebook.com/" . $urls);

$likes = array();
// Loop through the result and populate an array with the likes
for ($i = 0;$i < count($arr);$i++) {
    $url = $xml->link_stat[$i]->url;

    $counts = (int)$xml->link_stat[$i]->like_count;         
    $likes[] = array('likes' => $counts,'url' => $url);number_format(1000, 0, '.', ',');
}   

return $likes;

 }

 $array =      array("kylieminogue","SiaMusic","iggyazalea");
 $likes = getLikes($array);




 $likes = array_sort($likes, 'likes', SORT_DESC); 



 foreach ($likes as $key => $val) {

 $final = number_format($val['likes'], 0, '.', ',');

 echo "<li class='facebook'><div class='fb-page'><div class='rank'>" . $key . "</div>" . "<div class='thumb "  . $val['url'] . "'><div class='link'>" . $val['url'] . "</div></div>" . "<div class='likes'>" . $final . "</div></div></li><br />";

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this in getLikes(), inside the second loop:

```
$likes[] = array(
    'likes' => $counts,
    'url'   => $url,
    // create a hopefully unique class name
    'class' => strtolower($arr[$i]) . '-' . $i
);
// After this you call number_format without receiving its value, why?
```

Then in the HTML you change

```
"<div class='thumb "  . $val['url'] . "
```

for

```
"<div class='thumb "  . $val['class'] . "
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes thats exactly it! I replaced strtolower($arr[$i]) with a word.. because that adds the url as the class again. Now it's working, don't know abaout the number_format, but the formatting is working.